# hibernate select value coverage

Tags: mysql, database

I execute the following sql code, I want to get the "parent.name,child.name", but the value of the returned list is "parent.name,parent.name"? Could anyone help? the database is mysql

```
String sql = "select parent.name,child.name from CATEGORY as parent,CATEGORY as child where child.CATEGORY_ID=7 and child.SUB_TYPE in (80,81) and child.PARENT_ID=parent.ID;";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
return query.list();
```

the desired result:

```
parent.name child.name
  a            d
  b            e
  c            f
```

the current result:

```
parent.name child.name
  a            a
  b            b
  c            c
```

By the way, I can get the right result in SQLyog client by executing the sql.

Comment: How do you iterate the results?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's ensured the sql statement is correct via your description, and then just get the object array like following:

```
for(Object[] obj : results) {
  obj[0]  // parent name
  obj[1]  // child name
}
```

Maybe help you:)